# Plugin settings page template

Tags: templates, dashboard, options

When creating plug-ins for WordPress, there are times when you need to make a settings panel. Sometimes, you need more than one page, and they can be quite complicated.

So far, I have been programming/coding them alone. I try to make most of the WordPress original Admin design, but for sophisticated panels, I get a spaghetti of PHP and HTML code.
Also, every time, I have to write code that gets the data submitted by the user, analyses and saves it, and return a response.

What solution are you using for your plugins? Are you using a template engine, or just mixing PHP code with HTML? Are there ready framework that offers such a solution?

**Update**

I found the solution to this problem. It's provided by WordPress, and it's very simple and intuitive. This [blog post](http://www.presscoders.com/wordpress-settings-api-explained/) describes how to use the settings API which allows to create a settings/option page with ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed some frameworks

- [WP Alchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/)
- [Rilwis Meta Box Class](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2011/03/meta-box-script-update-v30.html)
- etc... google will lead your way, as well as the in site search for both packages.

Comment: Thanks, but Google didn't help.

Comment: Hope the in site search helps: [WP Alchemy](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=WP+Alchemy) and [Rilwis](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Rilwis&submit=search)

Comment: Well, I checked Alchemy and I'm not sure if that's what I really need. I don't need a custom metabox or post type. I need a template/framework to generate a personalized admin panel.

Comment: Jep. And you can use that to build all the input stuff and meta boxes. Else search on github for the bigger well known frameworks. They normally got stuff like that.